# utils does not contain progress_bar_downloader

Tags: python

The following line is casuing an error

```
from utils import progress_bar_downloader
```

and the error is

```
NameError: name 'progress_bar_downloader' is not defined
```

and I cannot able to find the solution. I installed utils using pip.

Comment: There are two problems here: (1) A mocha.js `utils` doesn't have anything to do with Python (2) The https://pypi.org/project/utils/ package you've installed doesn't have a `progress_bar_downloader`.

Comment: The link is javascript package not python one